# Does the 'cat' argument in query_posts fetch posts from subcategories as well as the given ID?

Tags: categories, query-posts

Hello friends I am new to wordpress.

I have used query like this query_posts('cat=1,2,3')

now If category 1 is parent of 2 and 3.

then query_posts('cat=1') and query_posts('cat=1,2,3') will get same posts or not?
or how can I manage If I want to include posts form subcategories.

Comment: Title is pretty incoherent. Proposed edited title: "Does the 'cat' argument in query_posts fetch posts from subcategories as well as the given ID?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: Yes.

Your question is about the [query_posts Wordpress PHP function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). The link I've placed is the official wordpress codex documentation for that function.

For your example it states:

> Display posts from only one category ID (and any children of that category):
>
> `query_posts('cat=4');`

I hope this information is helpful. You find more infos in codex, the function is pretty powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `cat=x` get's posts in x and all sub-categories, if you don't want this behavior doing `category__in => array( x )` will only get posts specifically in that category.

Comment: To seal the deal you can also use category__not_in which lets you exclude specific categories, in case you want to exclude particular children but include all others.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I have to submit an answer. To map Joe Hoyle's answer on to query_posts, you'd do the following:

query_posts('category__in=1');

That'd would give you just the main category, without the subcategories.

It's not what the OP was asking for, but I found this via Google when searching for how to just show the main category, so others may find this too.